# Screen recorder for android which records only particular app and excluding notifications and overlays

Tags: android, screen-recording

I was trying to make a screen recorder which can record sessions only of a particular app like if i selected fb it will only record fb apps and chats and will exclude or just don't record any element from another app like any apps notification or overlay just like obs in pc just record sessions from an app.
Any guidance will help me a lot.

Comment: Hi, Welcome, What have you done so far? Show your code and describe what exactly is not working. Please read this before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask